# Can I share the same input and volume control among several PAM87610-based audio amplifier boards?

Tags: amplifier

Is it possible? I wonder if I can feed several PAM8610 audio amplifier boards by connecting their input in parallel, sharing the same volume potentiometer and signal input.

**Sort of like this:**

[image]

**Datasheet**
[PAM8610 datasheet PDF](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1102988/Diodes/PAM8610/1)

[image]

Comment: Please provide a data sheet link to the PAM8610 module and IC Also explain how each module is powered.

Comment: What are the specs of the signal source, specs of the volume pot, and specs of module input, and how many modules there are?

Comment: @Justme signal source: cell phone headphone plug; volume potentiometer: 20k as seems to be the max listed in Table 1 from datasheet PDF; number of modules: from 2 up to 10

Comment: Diodes Inc. bought PAM company or is making copies of PAM amplifiers and the Diodes Inc. datasheet is missing the table from PAM's datasheet. The PAM8610 amplifier has an internal DC volume control but they do not say the current or resistance of the volume control. PAM's datasheet shows the variation of input resistance when the DC volume control is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting multiple amplifiers to the same signal source is perfectly valid. This will work just fine.

Make sure that all amps are connected to the same power ground. (It's easiest if you just power all of them from the same power supply.)

The input impedance will also drop in proportion to the number of amps you connect together. Each amp has an input impedance of 15kOhms. Your volume pot's resistance should be significantly smaller than 15k/n, where n is the number of amps you connected together. Alternatively, you can add a preamp to drive the inputs of the other amps.

Comment: Perfectly valid if you know it can be done, but the module specs are unknown, so do you know something about the module why it is possible and works just fine? There are also N modules where the amount of modules is unknown. So it depends how much each module loads the source and what impedance pot you use and how big a load the source can drive.

Comment: The OP showed a picture of the module. I simply identified it and looked it up.

Comment: Cool. Can you give a link to it to figure out input impedance? Only problem is the unknown amount of N amps and potentiometer value and source impedance.

Comment: The input is directly connected to the PAM8610's INN pin: https://www.makershop.de/module/audio/pam8610/ https://www.makershop.de/download/pam8610-schematic.png Unfortunately, the PAM8610's datasheet doesn't list the input impedance. The inputs of multiple amps can be safely connected in parallel, though. Assuming that the amp's frequency response extends down to 20Hz or lower, the input impedance should be about 10k given the 1µF coupling capacitors shown in the schematic. (Edit: Found it, it's 15k. https://www.sycelectronica.com.ar/diseno/AR-PAM8610.pdf )

Comment: @Justme N wouldn't be larger than 8 or 10 modules...

Comment: @AramAlvarez You might want to add a preamp then. A simple OpAmp voltage buffer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it will work depends on multiple things like your phone output and expectations.

The module is said to have 15 kohm input impedance. That might be somewhat low value for a line level input, but not unreasonably low. The problem is when you parallel 10 modules, so the input impedance of the combined amplifiers will be 1500 ohms, which is unreasonable for a line level input.

Fortunately mobile phones are mean to drive high loads such as 32 ohm headphones, so directly connected it may not be a problem. Some Android phones require that for headphone detection the resistance must be less than 1k, these phones likely detect that it is connected to line level input.

The 20k volume pot with phone driving it and 1500 ohm load impedance from amplifiers may be problematic. The volume might be difficult to adjust with the pot, it might be too loud at max volume but drop rapidly when turned slightly down so most of the range can be just too low. But it depends on the module gain and and speaker sensitivity what kind of adjustment range you are looking for and if that is a linear or logarithmic pot or does it have a special resistance curve for audio volume control.

Answer (score -1):

From the diagram I understand that the inputs are single-ended. And, from the diagram I understand that you are planning to use a pot at the input for volume control. If the levels are way lower than line levels (e.g. 100 mV) it may not be a good idea to use carbon potentiometers, because they are noisy and this will be heard on the output. Otherwise, won't be a problem.

The chip has inherent volume control but I can't see from the image if a related connection is present on the board. If it is then make use of it.

Comment: I have uploaded a magnified photo of that board...

Comment: @AramAlvarez no, unfortunately there's no input for volume control. What's the amplitude of your signals?